# How to schedule movement of data between 2 tables in different databases on the same Kusto cluster

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there any automated (Scheduled) way to periodically move data between two tables belonging to different databases on the same Kusto cluster? 'Continuous-Data export' feature does not work across different databases. One could orchestrate it through Azure Data Factory somehow, but it sounds like an overkill. Isn't there anything at Kusto level for scheduling this sort of data movement? Continuous Data export sounds very ideal if it didn't have limitation of not working across databases.

Comment: please comment if your have further questions, or mark you question resolved if you feel you got the response you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, there is no such capabilities in ADX.

It is however easy to setup, using your favorite scheduler (for instance, [Azure Schedular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/scheduler/scheduler-intro)), or simply using [Azure Timed Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer).

Azure functions are easier in this sense, because they are very easy to setup (and provide access to you ADX cluster resource).

Once you do, you can:

1. Use `.set-or-append` as Yoni's suggested like so (from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/data-ingestion/ingest-from-query)):

```
.set-or-append async ArchiveTable <| 
   LiveTable 
   | where CreatedOn < now() - time(30d)
```

Notice the `async` flag, so that your function won't block on waiting for completion.

You should know that this is a heavy operation and might take a while for a heavy table.

2. Trigger an export like you suggested, and set up an event-grid connection on the export location, so that ADX will reingest the data to you cluster. you can [read more about it here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid)

Answer (score 2):

You can run `.set-or-append` commands where the query part of the command is a cross-database query, in order to copy data (raw or processed) between tables in different databases (then drop the data in the source table, if it is no longer required, as you mentioned the intention is `move` and not `copy`)

Any scheduler/orchestrator which can issue control commands (such as `.set-or-append`) against your cluster is a valid option. A popular one Microsoft Flow: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/flow